# Batch loop removing character crashing when string contains space

Tags: batch-file

I have a loop which removes `\` characters and everything before them in a string until it contains none.

It operates fine until a space,  , character is in the string, e.g. `TEST AGAIN.txt`, which causes it to crash.

What causes this? and is there a better way to test if the string contains the `\` character?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
set INPUT=E:\FOLDERA\FOLDERB\TEST.TXT
echo %INPUT%
SET OUTPUT=%INPUT%

:AGAIN
SET OUTPUT=%OUTPUT:*\=%
if not x%OUTPUT:\=%==x%OUTPUT% (
GOTO AGAIN
)
echo %OUTPUT%
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are getting is because you aren't protecting your variables and strings using doublequotes.

The recommended syntax for doing so is:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Input=E:\FoderA\FolderB\Test Loop.txt"
Echo %Input%
Set "Output=%Input%"

:Loop
Set "Output=%Output:*\=%"
If /I Not "x%Output:\=%"=="x%Output%" (
    GoTo Loop
)
Echo %Output%
Pause
Exit /B
```

You also asked for a way to test if the string contains a `\` character; you can do so like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Not "%Input:\=%"=="%Input%" (Echo Contains \) Else Echo Does not contain \
Pause
```

You also asked if there was a better way of doing this.

You could use a built in metavariable modifier like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Input=E:\FolderA\FolderB\Test.txt"
For %%A In ("%Input%") Do Set "Output=%%~nxA"
Echo %Output%
Pause
```

These are the main modifiers:

```bat
%~A         - expands %A removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fA        - expands %A to a fully qualified path name
%~dA        - expands %A to a drive letter only
%~pA        - expands %A to a path only
%~nA        - expands %A to a file name only
%~xA        - expands %A to a file extension only
```

Because you've used the term input, if that is coming as an input parameter, `%1`, then you can modify that metavariable parameter directly:

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo Input is: %~1
Echo Output is %~nx1
Pause
```

As you can see in my examples, the modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

```bat
%~dpA       - expands %A to a drive letter and path only
%~nxA       - expands %A to a file name and extension only
```

Finally if you want to get really creative, *and confused*, you could do it like this too:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Input=E:\FolderA\FolderB\Test.txt"
Set "Output=%Input:\="&Set "Output=%"
Echo %Output%
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use quotes when comparing two things with an `if`.

```
if not "%OUTPUT:*\=%"=="%OUTPUT%" (
```

When %OUTPUT% contains a space, batch is reading `if not xTEST` as the command, which is not valid syntax.